# pass extra trough activity result is always null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I am trying to pass a unique id between activity, so i do something like this on activity1:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this,FotosForPlant.class);
    i.putExtra("plantId",id);
    startActivity(i);
```

on the FotosForPlant acitivity oncreate i should receive the extra with the plantId.

**So i did this:**

```
String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("plantId");
```

but i keep get a null value from the key, as you guys can see the keys are the same, what is going on? :S

Comment: What type is `id`?

Comment: int, it must be string right?

Comment: or use `getStringExtra()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)